# I've written remainder(x,y) in OCaml. Is there more efficient than O(n)?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

Here's my code:

```
let rem x y =
  let rec aux acc i n =
    if i=n then acc else
    if acc+1=y then aux 0 (i+1) n else
    aux (acc+1) (i+1) n in
  aux 0 0 x;;
```

I'm just learning OCaml and I wonder:

1. Is this tail recursive?
2. Is there a more efficient algorithm, i.e., operating in better than linear time?

Comment: I do not clearly understand what are you trying to achieve. If you want to implement `mod` function using sequence of additions your solution can be cheaper for when `x div y` is low and more expensive than `x mod y` when `x div y` is large because built-in `mod` probably can be very fast if suitabe processor instruction exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know OCaml, but I know enough similar languages that I think I can read that well enough to answer.  Still, take this with a grain of salt.

That is tail recursive.  You either return a value, or return the result of a recursive call that depends only on its input parameters that are known at the time of the call.

There is a more efficient algorithm.  Hint: repeated subtraction.  (That may not be the most efficient algorithm.)

You don't actually use the parameter n, you could just use x directly in the same way you use y directly.  The name `rem` isn't the most descriptive; `remainder` would be better, but that particular function is mostly known as `mod` or `modulus`.

I would find this formatting more readable:

```
if i = n 
then acc 
else if acc+1 = y 
     then aux      0  (i+1) n 
     else aux (acc+1) (i+1) n
```